# verifying mysql connection with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm attempting to create a installer for a website that connect to a database and will create the database and tables if not present.

I'm adding a mysql connection verification form to make sure the server is actually online so they don't have to fill out the form again and again if it fails.

It sends data back each time and these are my results:

- If the host is indeed a host and the correct credentials are input, it sends a success message.
- If the host is indeed a host and the incorrect credentials are input, it sends a failure message.
- If the host is not a host and random credentials are input, no message returns and there's a failure in the console.

I'm wondering why this is, any ideas?

checkdb.php

```
<?php

    if( empty($_POST) ) {
        $output = array("error" => true, "text" => "You didn't fill out the form.");
        die(json_encode($output));
    } else {
        if( empty($_POST["db_host"]) ) {
            $output = array("error" => true, "text" => "You didn't fill out the host field.");
            echo json_encode($output);
            die();
        }
        if( empty($_POST["db_user"]) ) {
            $output = array("error" => true, "text" => "You didn't fill out the username field.");
            echo json_encode($output);
            die();
        }

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $_POST["db_host"], $_POST["db_user"], $_POST["db_pass"]);
            if($db == false) {
                $output = array("error" => true, "text" => "There was an error connecting to the database.");
                die(json_encode($output));
            } else {
                $output = array("error" => false, "text" => "Successfully connected to database, proceed with installation.");
                die(json_encode($output));
            }
            //$db->exec("CREATE DATABASE `mcm_db`;") or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            //$sql = file_get_contents("defaults/sql.sql");
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            $output = array("error" => true, "text" => $ex->getMessage());
            die(json_encode($output));
        }

        $output = array("error" => true, "text" => "TEST THIS NEVER RETURNS");
        die(json_encode($output));
    }

?>
```

install.php (acts as javascript file)

```
<?php

    if( file_exists("../../app/Configuration/config.php") ) {
        require "../../app/Configuration/config.php";
    } else if( file_exists("../../install/defaults/config.php") ) {
        require "../../install/defaults/config.php";
    } else {
        die("Could not find the default configuration file or the modified configuration file.");
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

?>

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#checkdb').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = {
            'db_host': $('input[name=db_host]').val(),
            'db_user': $('input[name=db_user]').val(),
            'db_pass': $('input[name=db_pass]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo URL; ?>/install/checkdb.php',
            data: formData,
            success: function (json_data) {
                var data_array = $.parseJSON(json_data);
                if (data_array['error'] == false) {
                    $.notify(data_array['text'], "success");
                    $('#checkdb input').addClass('input-success');
                } else {
                    $.notify(data_array['text'], "error");
                    $('#checkdb input').addClass('input-failure');
                }
            },
            fail: function () {
                $.notify("There was an error while submitting the AJAX request.", "error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

index.php

```
<?php

    if( file_exists("../app/Configuration/config.php") ) {
        require "../app/Configuration/config.php";
    } else if( file_exists("../install/defaults/config.php") ) {
        require "../install/defaults/config.php";
    } else {
        die("Could not find the default configuration file or the modified configuration file.");
    }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>MCManager Installer</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/css/css.install.php" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/js/jquery.notify.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="content container">
            <div id="checkdb_msg" class="msg"><p></p></div>
            <div class="module">
                <div class="module-header">
                    <h4>MCManager Installer</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="module-body module-padding">
                    <form id="checkdb" method="post" action="<?php echo URL;?>/installer/checkdb.php">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="db_host" placeholder="Host">
                                <br />
                                <input type="text" name="db_user" placeholder="Username">
                                <br />
                                <input type="text" name="db_pass" placeholder="Password">
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Test Connection" id="checkdb_btn" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>/resources/js/install.php"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the failure in the console?

Comment: @AdamKonieska Unexpected token <

Comment: @AdamKonieska I console.log'd my data returned, and it returns a 2002 sql error or "unknown host". Which is good! But how can I add it so that a message pops up for that?

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to sanitize the input going into `$.notify()`.  If `data_array['text']` has the `<` that is breaking something being added by `$ex->getMessage()`, that could be your problem.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Do you have any ideas on how to sanitize it? I've tried using the utf8_encode function but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I would update your PHP catch to return a generic `"Oops, the things didnt database correctly"` instead of `$ex->getMessage()`. Giving PDOExceptions to your users might expose information about your database that you wouldn't want them to know, and the error message might be overly technical and unnecessary to users that cant do anything about it.

Comment: @AdamKonieska Well this is just for an installer. This just sets up the database and configuration for the people that would like to use my project. After installation, users of their sites won't be able to see it.